# What is the rightway to set an openlayers popup size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers

I am using the following function to set the size of a popup. However, I am noticing that always the size of the popup exceeds the size set by me and I have right margin to the left (see below).

Is there any problem with my code?

```
function onFeatureSelect(feature) {

    selectedFeature = feature;
    mydescription='<a href="' + feature.attributes.path + '">' + '<div class="visual">' + feature.attributes.image + '</div>' + '<div class="textual"><h2 class="title">' + feature.attributes.title + '</h2>' +'<div class="description">' + feature.attributes.description + '</div></div></a>';
    popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken",
    feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
    new OpenLayers.Size(500,300), mydescription , null, true, onPopupClose);
    popup.autoSize = true;
    popup.panMapIfOutOfView = false;
    feature.popup = popup;
    map.addPopup(popup);
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hard to say, I suggest you debug the HTML with FireBug. Maybe you have a width set on your outer DIV or some margin on it

Answer (score 1):

Just set `popup.autoSize = false;` and the Popup will be 500px X 300px as